# How to convert a CSV with paragraphs to JSON on macOS's BSD Terminal?

Tags: csv, json

I have a huge text file that contains this structure:

```
title;description;date
```

The problem is that `description` main contain paragraphs, like:

```
title;description;data
MyText;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est dolor, molestie a rhoncus vel, congue sed diam. Vestibulum pellentesque libero eleifend dolor finibus vestibulum. Curabitur at suscipit tellus, at viverra ex. Nulla sem nibh, laoreet a porta a, convallis ac augue. Aliquam diam sapien, rutrum sed nulla lobortis, hendrerit rutrum diam. Donec tellus quam, maximus at mollis sit amet, consequat eget orci. Duis id vestibulum metus. Nulla convallis tortor diam, a tempus quam mollis sed. Aliquam at fermentum nibh, quis sodales orci. Maecenas viverra ultrices lobortis. Morbi viverra, tortor in mattis tincidunt, augue erat condimentum leo, a dignissim nulla lacus ac augue. Sed tincidunt rutrum sapien, sodales commodo sapien. Sed ultrices, augue vitae porta viverra, eros magna pellentesque leo, in bibendum enim enim non nulla. Nullam vel venenatis leo.

Sed sed vulputate nulla. Nullam hendrerit justo quis ante aliquet ullamcorper. Praesent at rhoncus ipsum, in sodales felis. Nam eu ante accumsan urna tempus rutrum at in felis. Maecenas eleifend enim nec augue eleifend, ut sagittis leo tincidunt. In non felis pretium, accumsan mi sit amet, hendrerit lectus. Nullam auctor mi non ligula aliquam commodo. Nunc mollis consequat purus, sit amet rutrum elit sodales sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Ut a tempor urna. Etiam vitae venenatis ex.

Nunc ut mattis nibh. Morbi varius accumsan purus, vel facilisis eros suscipit id. Sed non accumsan arcu, pretium pulvinar urna. Quisque a neque faucibus, condimentum velit eget, varius lorem. Duis varius iaculis ullamcorper. Maecenas vitae fringilla mi, ultrices finibus justo. Suspendisse vel nibh tortor. Nullam ullamcorper justo augue, molestie lacinia lorem varius et. Etiam sed pulvinar metus, ac euismod arcu. Morbi laoreet dolor volutpat, tempor nunc sit amet, lobortis ipsum. Quisque posuere commodo sollicitudin. Vivamus consectetur ligula sed ante tristique congue. Duis faucibus lacus tellus, sed consectetur purus ornare vitae.;2023-07-12
```

How do I convert that to JSON using macOS's terminal?

NOTE: I don't want to use online converters because of sensitive data.

I have tried stuff like

```
ruby -r json -r csv -e 'puts CSV.parse(STDIN, headers:true).map(&:to_h).to_json' < myFile.csv > myFile.json
```

But these fail. I suspect because they interpret the line breaks in the paragraph as the end of a CSV line and the beginning of the next.

When I do a `cat -e myFile.csv` I see `$` as the marker for the lines and for the breaks inside the paragraphs. Same marker!

When I issue a `file` on the `CSV` I see

```
Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

I do not have a clue how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: What creates this data, and does it not know about CSV quoting rules?  Usually, a CSV field is allowed to contain literal newlines and embedded field delimiters if the field is double-quoted (embedded double quotes are written as `""`).  What you show is not CSV.

Comment: Are there any guarantees about the data in the `description` field? Like, "it will never ever contain a double quote or a semi-colon"?

Comment: yeah sorry for the premature answer. if your data isn't valid CSV, and that seems to be the case, no CSV parser will like it, and you'll have to bring it into a compliant form first (for example by replacing the newline character on lines that do not contain a`;` to a placeholder or escape sequence), but that again would require the data to be well-formed in other ways – in other words, from your example, it'd just seem you're dealing with pretty broken data that might need to manually be checked during conversion to something valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you have a wrong CSV. You should have double quotes delimiters in the cells that have a carriage return inside (an example below).

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/installing-miller/), and a right CSV you can run

```
mlr --c2j --ifs ";" cat input.csv
```

to get

```json
{ "title": "MyText", "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est dolor, molestie a rhoncus vel, congue sed diam. Vestibulum pellentesque libero eleifend dolor finibus vestibulum. Curabitur at suscipit tellus, at viverra ex. Nulla sem nibh, laoreet a porta a, convallis ac augue. Aliquam diam sapien, rutrum sed nulla lobortis, hendrerit rutrum diam. Donec tellus quam, maximus at mollis sit amet, consequat eget orci. Duis id vestibulum metus. Nulla convallis tortor diam, a tempus quam mollis sed. Aliquam at fermentum nibh, quis sodales orci. Maecenas viverra ultrices lobortis. Morbi viverra, tortor in mattis tincidunt, augue erat condimentum leo, a dignissim nulla lacus ac augue. Sed tincidunt rutrum sapien, sodales commodo sapien. Sed ultrices, augue vitae porta viverra, eros magna pellentesque leo, in bibendum enim enim non nulla. Nullam vel venenatis leo.\n\nSed sed vulputate nulla. Nullam hendrerit justo quis ante aliquet ullamcorper. Praesent at rhoncus ipsum, in sodales felis. Nam eu ante accumsan urna tempus rutrum at in felis. Maecenas eleifend enim nec augue eleifend, ut sagittis leo tincidunt. In non felis pretium, accumsan mi sit amet, hendrerit lectus. Nullam auctor mi non ligula aliquam commodo. Nunc mollis consequat purus, sit amet rutrum elit sodales sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Ut a tempor urna. Etiam vitae venenatis ex.\n\nNunc ut mattis nibh. Morbi varius accumsan purus, vel facilisis eros suscipit id. Sed non accumsan arcu, pretium pulvinar urna. Quisque a neque faucibus, condimentum velit eget, varius lorem. Duis varius iaculis ullamcorper. Maecenas vitae fringilla mi, ultrices finibus justo. Suspendisse vel nibh tortor. Nullam ullamcorper justo augue, molestie lacinia lorem varius et. Etiam sed pulvinar metus, ac euismod arcu. Morbi laoreet dolor volutpat, tempor nunc sit amet, lobortis ipsum. Quisque posuere commodo sollicitudin. Vivamus consectetur ligula sed ante tristique congue. Duis faucibus lacus tellus, sed consectetur purus ornare vitae.", "data": "2023-07-12" }
```

A right CSV

```
title;description;data
MyText;"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est dolor, molestie a rhoncus vel, congue sed diam. Vestibulum pellentesque libero eleifend dolor finibus vestibulum. Curabitur at suscipit tellus, at viverra ex. Nulla sem nibh, laoreet a porta a, convallis ac augue. Aliquam diam sapien, rutrum sed nulla lobortis, hendrerit rutrum diam. Donec tellus quam, maximus at mollis sit amet, consequat eget orci. Duis id vestibulum metus. Nulla convallis tortor diam, a tempus quam mollis sed. Aliquam at fermentum nibh, quis sodales orci. Maecenas viverra ultrices lobortis. Morbi viverra, tortor in mattis tincidunt, augue erat condimentum leo, a dignissim nulla lacus ac augue. Sed tincidunt rutrum sapien, sodales commodo sapien. Sed ultrices, augue vitae porta viverra, eros magna pellentesque leo, in bibendum enim enim non nulla. Nullam vel venenatis leo.

Sed sed vulputate nulla. Nullam hendrerit justo quis ante aliquet ullamcorper. Praesent at rhoncus ipsum, in sodales felis. Nam eu ante accumsan urna tempus rutrum at in felis. Maecenas eleifend enim nec augue eleifend, ut sagittis leo tincidunt. In non felis pretium, accumsan mi sit amet, hendrerit lectus. Nullam auctor mi non ligula aliquam commodo. Nunc mollis consequat purus, sit amet rutrum elit sodales sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Ut a tempor urna. Etiam vitae venenatis ex.

Nunc ut mattis nibh. Morbi varius accumsan purus, vel facilisis eros suscipit id. Sed non accumsan arcu, pretium pulvinar urna. Quisque a neque faucibus, condimentum velit eget, varius lorem. Duis varius iaculis ullamcorper. Maecenas vitae fringilla mi, ultrices finibus justo. Suspendisse vel nibh tortor. Nullam ullamcorper justo augue, molestie lacinia lorem varius et. Etiam sed pulvinar metus, ac euismod arcu. Morbi laoreet dolor volutpat, tempor nunc sit amet, lobortis ipsum. Quisque posuere commodo sollicitudin. Vivamus consectetur ligula sed ante tristique congue. Duis faucibus lacus tellus, sed consectetur purus ornare vitae.";2023-07-12
```

Comment: F A N T A S T I C ! Thanks.